# CF7 Ajax isn't working when called inside WooCommerce "woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button" hook

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, ajax, plugin-contact-form-7

I am trying to place a CF7 Contact form on the product details page. I have used the WooCommerce hook `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button` for that.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'custom_before_add_to_cart_btn' );

function custom_before_add_to_cart_btn() {
    echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="69" title="Contact form 1"]' );
}
```

But on submitting the form, the page is actually getting refreshed. The Ajax is no longer working. I got no errors in the Console, so i don't think it's a JS issue.

It is a fresh WooCommerce Storefront Installation, no other plug-ins or anything. Do you guys have any idea how this is happening and how can I get around this ?

This is the screencast of what's exactly happening : [Screencast](https://vimeo.com/476243539)

Comment: is the cf7 pluign `script.js` bein gloaded?  Likely not due to the fact that the woocommerece hook fires after the page script enqueue action.  I would try to use `wp_register_script` to register cf7 scripts/css on page enqueue action.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure when the `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button` action fires in the request sequence, but it could be worth adding the following code to your `functions.php` to see if it loads the CF7 js script files,

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pre_register_cf7_files');
function pre_register_cf7_files(){
  wp_register_style('contact-form-7', wpcf7_plugin_url( 'includes/css/styles.css' ), array(), WPCF7_VERSION, 'all' );
  wp_register_script( 'contact-form-7', wpcf7_plugin_url( 'includes/js/scripts.js' ), array( 'jquery' ), WPCF7_VERSION, true);
}
```

If this does not work, your only solution will be to hook your `custom_before_add_to_cart_btn` function earlier in the [request sequence](https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/hook/woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button).